# what to replace Hodge theory with if I don't know what complex numbers are

Tags: algebraic-geometry, hodge-theory

Q1: How do I prove $h^i(X,\Omega^j_X)=h^j(X,\Omega^i_X)$ for say $X$ smooth geometrically integral projective variety over some field of characteristic zero (I have a strong suspicion this should be true, maybe after changing hypotheses a bit)?

Q2: More vaguely, suppose I have some purely geometric result I see somewhere proved using hodge-theoretic methods, and I want to prove it without using hodge theory, what are the tools I'll have to use to do that?

Q2': For example, is there an algebraically defined cohomology theory for smooth projective varieties that carries hodge structures? (I suspect no, but then why not and what do we do about it?)

Comment: Depending on what you want to use it for, one can often replace "Hodge theory" by arguments involving the degeneration of the Hodge to de Rham spectral sequence. This relates the de Rham cohomology to the Hodge numbers you refer to. Everything in sight is algebraic and these can be used in many situations including positive characteristic.

Comment: I kinda suspected hodge-to-deRham might be the answer. Can you recommend me a readable introduction to the subject? ideally, with geometric applications in mind.

Comment: For right now I'll say I love the chapter in the book called Introduction to Hodge Theory (SMF/AMS Texts and Monographs) by Illusie called "Frobenius and Hodge Degeneration." It's been awhile since I looked at it, so I don't remember if the part about the spectral sequence is readable (I had seen this from other sources already when I first looked at this chapter), but it provides a pretty great introduction to some of the ideas you ask about in the question.